# How to loop through multiple arrays simultaniously?

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to vb, so sorry if my question has been asked before. I have searched but have not been able to find, or perhaps recognize, an answer. I am using visual studio 2010 and creating an app in vb.net.
I have 2 arrays named questions and answers.I want to traverse these 2 arrays simultaneously and retrieve the records from these 2 arrays.which i am doing with the following code.

```
 Dim sql As String = "SELECT QuestionId,Answer FROM tbl_Answers"
 Dim dt As DataTable = obj.GetDTbl(sql)
 For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows              
     SelectedAnswers += row("Answer").ToString & ","
 Next
 Dim Questions() As String = QuestionsIds.Split(",")
 For Each question In Questions
     Dim answers() As String = SelectedAnswers.Split(",")
     For Each answer In answers
         Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(plcHolderForm.FindControl("Question_" & question), RadioButtonList)


         rbl.SelectedIndex = rbl.Items.IndexOf(rbl.Items.FindByValue("answer".ToString))
```

In above code it is obviously can be seen that my outer for loop executes only once.I need to traverse above 2 for each loop such that against each question i can get  its answer which am retriving through FindByValue function

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is in `dt`? Is `Questions` an array of strings? Does every question have exactly one answer or can it have multiple (possibly wrong) answers?

Comment: Every question has only 1 answer.dt is data table. Questions is array of string which I split into no of questions, same way i split the answer array.

Comment: Maybe use a for loop instead of foreach?

Comment: Every question has one answer?? What numbers can you add together to get 10? 5 + 5? 3 + 7? 1 + 9? etc... Depends how the question is asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just loop through both question and answer in 1 generic for loop?

```
Dim CurQuestion as String
Dim CurAnswer as String
For i As Integer = 0 To Questions.Length - 1
    CurQuestion = Questions(i)
    CurAnswer = Answers(i)
    'Do what you need what current question and answer
Next
```

This assumes that you have the same number of questions and answers and they line up in their respective arrays.  If not you'll have to fine tune it to meet your specific need.

Comment: Thank you for your Reply.I am little bit confused how can i loop through both questions and answers array with 1 for loop..can you please elaborate your answer in more details.

Comment: It's a simple for loop, you are just iterating a variable called `i` from 0 to `Questions.Length-1`, then you can reference the current answer or question by taking the `ith` value of the array like `Answers(i)`